# Isotope error: sorter is not a function. Isotope not sorting

Tags: jquery-isotope

I am using Jquery Isotope. filtering seems to work fine but when I add the sort functionality i get two errors:

```
isotope Uncaught TypeError: sorter is not a function
```

and

```
$().isotope("reLayout") is not a valid method
```

here is my html and jquery:

HTML

```
<select id="sortBy" name="sort">
    <option value="pricelowtohigh">Price low to high</option>
    <option value="pricehightolow">Price high to low</option>
</select>


    <li class="block filter-john-doe filter-productname">
<a class="page-fade" href="{{ product.url }}">
        <div>
            <h2 class="small">John Doe</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
            <p><span class="price" data-price="995">£995</span></p>
        </div>
    </a>
</li>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    onHashchange();

    var $grid = $('.grid').isotope({
        itemSelector: '.block',
        layoutMode: 'fitRows',
        getSortData: {
            pricelowtohigh: '[data-price] parseInt',
            pricehightolow: '[data-price] parseInt',

        }
        sortAscending: {
            pricelowtohigh: true,
            pricehightolow: false
        }
    });
    var filters = {};

    $('.filter').change(function() {
        var $this = $(this);

        var $buttonGroup = $this.parents('.inputGroup');
        var filterGroup = $buttonGroup.attr('data-filter-group');

        filters[ filterGroup ] = $this.attr('data-filter');
        // combine filters
        var filterValue = concatValues( filters );
        $grid.isotope({ filter: filterValue });
    });

    $('#sortBy').change(function() {
        var sortValue = $(this).val();
        $grid.isotope({ sortBy: sortValue });
    });
});

$(window).load(function(){$(".grid").isotope('reLayout');});

 $(window).on( 'hashchange', function() {
        onHashchange();

    });

    // flatten object by concatting values
    function concatValues( obj ) {
        var value = '';
        for ( var prop in obj ) {
            value += obj[ prop ];
        }
        return value;
    }
```

Does anyone know why this is? Isotope doesn't have much support available as their git hub is strictly only for bug reports, and as this is probably just my ignorance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised that I didn't declare the array first - `sortBy: ['price']`
I also ended up finding a tidier way of declaring the ascending and descending function but parsing it directly onto the sortby function at the end. `$grid.isotope({ sortBy: 'price', sortAscending: isAscending });`

```
 var $grid = $('.grid').isotope({
            itemSelector: '.block',
            layoutMode: 'fitRows',
            getSortData: {
                price: '[data-price] parseInt',
                // pricehightolow: '[data-price] parseInt',

            },
            sortBy: ['price']

        });

        $('#sortBy').change(function() {
            var sortValue = $(this).val();
            console.log("sortBy "+sortValue);
            var isAscending = sortValue === 'pricelowtohigh' ? true : false;
            $grid.isotope({ sortBy: 'price', sortAscending: isAscending });
        });
```